# Assign corresponding values between two dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frame of different dimension, here an example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
                  ID = c(1:7),
                 coordinate = c(1, 5, 6, 4, 3, 7, 9),
                  var1 = c(0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 1, 3),
                 var3 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 6, 1))

 df2 <- data.frame(
                 ID = c(1, 5, 3),
                 coordinate = c(1, 7, 6),
                 area_name = c("A", "B", "C"))
```

The "coordinate" columns of both df1 and df2 have some points in common.

I would like to assign to each coordinate of df1 the corrisponding area_name from df2

I may use the "coordinate" values as pivot to join them, but I cannot reach a correct way.

Comment: Try merge() function

Comment: don't know how to use it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right